How can I solve a SyntaxError: The requested module './routes/pedidos.mjs' does not provide an export named 'default'
I'm new with Javascript and now I'm trying to make an api with express, but the import crashes with the following message:
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: The requested module './routes/pedidos.mjs' does not provide an export named 'default'
    at ModuleJob._instantiate (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:134:21)
    at async ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:217:5)
    at async ModuleLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:316:24)
    at async asyncRunEntryPointWithESMLoader (node:internal/modules/run_main:123:5)

Node.js v20.14.0`


How can I solve it? My files are this:
pedidos.mjs
import { Router } from "express";
import { ACCEPTED_ORIGINS } from "../middlewares/cors.mjs";

const router = Router()
export const pedidosRoutes = router

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    return res.json({ "id": "1" })
})

index.mjs 

import express from 'express'
import pedidosRoutes from './routes/pedidos.mjs'

const app = express()
const PORT = process.env.PORT ?? 3000

app.disable('x-powered-by')
app.use(json())
app.use('pedidos', pedidosRoutes)

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`im listening on port ${PORT}`)
})

I'm trying to import but i didn't accomplished.

I solved, I forgot the "{" and "}", now the problem is solved, how do I close it?

You can answer your question. Just do that and click the tick button.

Done, thank's @JayendraAwasthi

I solved, I forgot the "{" and "}", now the problem is solved.
Some image to understand it:
unsuccessful import in ESModules
